# Why does default constructor is called even when I am calling the parameterized constructor?

Tags: c++, class, stdmap, default-constructor

I have a class and I am creating an object of it using parameterized constructor. During this time both parameterized  and default constructor has been called.

Here is my snippet:

```
class student {
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    student() {
        cout << "Calling the default constructor\n";
    }
    student(string name1, int age1) {
        cout << "Calling the parameterized const\n";
        name = name1;
        age = age1;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << " name : " << name << " age : " << age << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    map<int, student> students;
    students[0] = student("bob", 25);
    students[1] = student("raven", 30);

    for (map<int, student>::iterator it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++) {
        cout << "The key is : " << it->first ;
        it->second.print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I am executing this snippet, my output is coming as:

Calling the parameterized const
Calling the default constructor
Calling the parameterized const
Calling the default constructor
The key is : 0 name : bob age : 25
The key is : 1 name : raven age : 30

So, I want to understand, if I am calling the parameterized constructor, why default constructor has been called after the parameterized constructor?

Comment: Unrelated, you can further improve this code by move-constructing your member variables from your `student` constructor by-value arguments in the member initialization list (which you're currently not using at all). Make no difference for the `age` member, but it avoids a string copy.

Comment: 'Cuz the `std::map` `[]` operator does some very silly things, proving that not even the bods behind the design of C++ are perfect.

Comment: @Bathsheba The alternative would be to throw an exception, which is also not ideal. But I agree that this is a gotcha that surprises most users at some point.

Answer (score 6):

Because [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will insert a default-constructed `student` firstly if the specified key doesn't exist. Then the inserted `student` gets assigned from the temporary `student` like `student("bob", 25)`.

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

You can use [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) instead.

```
students.insert({0, student("bob", 25)});
students.insert({1, student("raven", 30)});
```

Answer (score 4):

`students[0]` is constructing automatically the object using it's default constructor. `students[0] =` use the copy assignment operator, and `student("bob", 25)` calls the `parameterized constructor`.

You can use:

```
studets.insert(pair<int, student>(0, student("bob", 25)));
```

or:

```
studets.emplace(0, student("bob", 25));
```

To avoid the default constructor.

[From the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/map.access#2):

> ```
> T& operator[](const key_type& x);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Equivalent to: return try_­emplace(x).first->second;
>
> ```
> T& operator[](key_type&& x);
> ```
>
> ***Effects*: Equivalent to: return try_­emplace(move(x)).first->second;**
>
> ```
> T&       at(const key_type& x);
> const T& at(const key_type& x) const;
> ```
>
> *Returns*: A reference to the mapped_­type corresponding to x in* *this.
>
> *Throws*: An exception object of type out_­of_­range if no such element is present.
>
> *Complexity*: Logarithmic.